# Skip rows with NULL value

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I have this code I have been using to find the 50% exceedance value per hour and month. Attached is a picture of the data. There are some NULL values in the Gen columns and I need the code to skip those rows or else the results show as #VALUE.

```
Public Function PercentileDetectorYear(ByVal iYear As Integer, ByVal iMonth As Integer, ByVal isWeekend As Variant, ByVal iHour As Integer, _
                ByVal dataCol As Integer, ByVal SrchTable As Range, ByVal thisPercentile As Double) As Variant
    'scans a table, looking for specific month, isWeekend, and iHour values in specified columns of table.
    'Builds an array of contents meeting that criteria, then performs a Percentile computation on that dataset.
    Dim monCol As Integer
    Dim dayOfWeekCol As Integer
    Dim hourCol As Integer
    Dim iCt As Double
    Dim iRow As Double
    Dim dataObs() As Double
    Dim rtn As Variant
    Dim yearCol As Integer
    
    yearCol = 1
    monCol = 2
    dayOfWeekCol = 4
    hourCol = 5
    
    If isWeekend = True Then
        isWeekend = 1
    ElseIf isWeekend = False Then
        isWeekend = 0
    End If
    
    iCt = 0
    iRow = 1
    With SrchTable
        Do While iRow <= .Rows.Count
        
            If .Cells(iRow, yearCol) = iYear And .Cells(iRow, monCol) = iMonth And .Cells(iRow, dayOfWeekCol).Value = isWeekend And .Cells(iRow, hourCol) = iHour Then
                If iCt = 0 Then
                    ReDim dataObs(0)
                    dataObs(0) = .Cells(iRow, dataCol)
                    iCt = iCt + 1
                Else
                    ReDim Preserve dataObs(iCt)
                    dataObs(iCt) = .Cells(iRow, dataCol)
                    iCt = iCt + 1
                End If

            End If
            iRow = iRow + 1
        Loop
    End With
    
    rtn = Application.Percentile(dataObs, thisPercentile)
    
    PercentileDetectorYear = rtn
'    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    
End Function
```

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! What do you consider as null? Are zeros considered as null values?

Comment: Hi thank you! Zeros are fine, there are some boxes with the text NULL which I believe is what is returning the #VALUE

Comment: `isWeekend = ABS(isWeekend)` will return 0/1 as a shorter way of writing the `IF....ELSEIF` block.